# Движение с коллизией через Update и FixedUpdate, что такое "телепортация" в контексте физического движка в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-faq

Будет ли физический движок просчитывать коллизии, если двигать физическое тело через `Transform` в `Update`?

Что подразумевают, когда говорят "телепортация" в контексте передвижения физического объекта?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Как работает любой физический движок (в геймдеве)

Первое, что нужно усвоить: PhysX, как и любой физический движок - это **дискретная система**. Такие движки просчитывают состояние физической системы с определенной частотой. Если брать в пример Unity с ее PhysX и понятием `fixed time step` - это, по сути, **шаг дискретизации**. При дефолтном значении в `dt = 0.02s` **частота дискретизации** равна `1/0.02 = 50hz` или `50 frames / second`. И каждый квант времени происходит просчет физики (да и обычный `Update` работает точно так же, там только частота немного повыше как минимум по умолчанию в Unity, если `target fps = 60`, да и не вижу особого смысла делать физические апдейты чаще логических).

---

### [Дискретизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Немного отойдем от темы в сторону и посмотрим на эту замечательную тему. По ссылке выше можно почитать какие-то умные математические слова, это в общем случае почти никак не относится к теме этого вопроса, но чуть позже это пригодится.
Представим, что у нас есть какой-то объект, который движется по синусоиде примерно так: `position = (Time.time, 0, sin(Time.time))`, чисто теоретически мы получим синусоиду. Допустим, у нас есть 2 версии игры: с `fps = 10` и `fps = 100`, получаем примерно такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мы видим, версия с `fps = 10` хоть и похожа на наш синус, но есть явные “промахи". Или, другими словами, **чем меньше шаг дискретизации, тем более точный получается результат на выходе**.

---

### А что там все-таки с физикой?

Возьмем простейший пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Двигающийся объект и стена-коллайдер перед ним, пока что в настройках ничего не трогаем и пытаемся двигать наш объект кодом, который написан во всех туториалах по Unity:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 10f));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь попробуем все то же самое сделать через `Update` и `Transform.Translate`:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 10f) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если это препятствие убрать, что вполне легальная операция, ну мало ли у нас персонаж уперся в дверь, а она открылась. Правда нашему кубику резко поплохело:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*С передвижением через FixedUpdate объект не дергается и не отлетает в рандомные стороны.*

---

### Почему так происходит?

Вот этот конкретный пример вызывался `fps = 144` и `Fixed time step = 0.02`, т.е. физический `fps = 50`. `Transform.position` переписывают оба этих потока, `Update` двигает объект вперед, физический движок видит, что у нас тут коллизия и вытворяет **[constraint resolution](http://allenchou.net/2013/12/game-physics-resolution-contact-constraints/)** - выталкивает объект назад, чтобы коллайдеры не пересекались. А очередь примерно такая:
`Update -> Update -> Update -> Physics -> Update -> Update -> Update -> Physics -> …`
**Грубо говоря**, физики тут в `144/50 ~ 3` раза меньше, поэтому и кажется, что объекты внутри и куб дергается.

**Что делать с большими скоростями?**

Цель: задать большую скорость объекту. Получается что-то такое:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 500f);
}
```

Вроде все по “канону”, но теперь наш объект не сталкивается с препятствие. Почему так? Все просто, по умолчанию в Unity работает самый логичный и легкий алгоритм - **дискретный** “тест” на коллизию. 
Посмотрим, что там по кадрам происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Физический движок даже и не подозревает о какой-то там преграде – проверяет он это только во время вызовов `FixedUpdate`, а, как мы видим, он ни с чем там не сталкивается в 1 и 2 кадре -> движок ничего и не делает.

Для таких ситуаций существует целый набор разных CCD (Continuous Collision Detection) алгоритмов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Они **разные** и нужны для разных ситуаций, какие-то быстрые, какие-то медленные, тема интересная, но вопрос не об этом, так остановимся на самом “простом” `Continuous` режиме. После переключения наш объект остановится из-за преграды, вот в принципе и все, это просто работает. Логика там простая: вместо проверки на каждом вызове `FixedUpdate` физический движок до перемещения объекта под влиянием каких-то сил проверяет специальными алгоритмами (в этом и заключается их различие), не сталкивается ли объект с чем-то во время движения в этом кадре.

---

### Почему нельзя перемещать физические объекты в Update?

Потому что **логический** и **физический** движки – это два разных потока. Unity самостоятельно ими управляет, но это не значит, что их нельзя сломать.

Наконец мы подобрались к термину **Телепортация**, первое, что стоит усвоить: этот термин не несет в себе смысла без физического или логического движка, он существует только в их непосредственной связке. Представим ситуацию:
Есть объект, на него ничего не взаимодействует, `velocity = 0`, в общем, стоит он и не шевелится… **с точки зрения физического движка**. А вот в `Update` пропишем `transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1000f) * Time.deltaTime);`. 
Вот и все, физический движок ничего не двигает и думает, что объект неподвижен, а на деле он двигается, в итоге получаем такую ситуацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С точки зрения физического движка **неподвижный** элемент сменил свою позицию – это и есть **телепортация**. А поскольку физический движок ничего не знает о движении объект – просчитывать коллизии с помощью CCD он не будет.

**А как же алгоритмы CCD?**

Они не будут работать, вот и все. А причина проста: эти алгоритмы ведут расчет исходя из данных в `RigidBody`, который неподвижен с точки зрения физического движка -> он либо в данном кадре с чем-то столкнулся, либо CCD не найдет коллизий, если вообще будет что-то считать у статичного объект ради оптимизации.

Может показаться, что перенос `Transform` кода в `FixedUpdate` может как-то решить проблему, но нет, это будет **все та же телепортация, только с другой частотой**.

---

### Горькая, но все же пилюля

Говоря об оптимизации, я обратил внимание на “чем меньше шаг дискретизации, тем более точный получается результат на выходе”. В нашем случае шаг дискретизации – это `Fixed time step`. Чем он меньше, тем чаще физический движок будет разрешать всякие физические вопросы, в том числе и проверки на коллизию и constraint resolution.

**Так почему же это решение не самое оптимальное?**

Чаще считается физика – больше нагрузка на ЦП. Обычно такое решение не самое оптимальное, но “обычно” =/= “всегда”, так что и такое применяют.

По крайней мере я советую поменять константу дискретизации (если ваша игра идет в `60fps`) либо на `16.7ms`, чтобы физический движок шел в `60fps` - это “синхронизирует” логический и физический потоки. Либо на `33.4ms`, чтобы физический движок шел в 30fps – чтобы они отличались в **целое число** раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "там только частота немного повыше". Наоборот, у `FixedUpdate` частота выше.

Comment: Только хотел исправить, а это написали до меня :) + И у FixedUpdate() так же частота не всегда постоянна. Хоть и более стабильная чем у Update().

Comment: @Suvitruf, я, видимо, что-то путаю, но каким образом у `FixedUpdate` с `dt=0.02` частота будет выше, чем у `Update` с `dt=0.0167`?

Comment: @Andrew, выше + под "постоянной" частотой в сравнении с `Update` имелся в виду `Fixed timestep`, при соблюдении требований к железу такой `FixedUpdate` будет практически всегда стабилен.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да, ты прав, частота апдейта выше. Это был мой тупняк :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да я по привычке в рамках 25-30 fps просто.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу RiotBr3aker:

> А теперь попробуем все то же самое сделать через `Update` и `Transform.Translate`:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 10f) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно понимать причину этой тряски: **эта тряска на гифке возникает по одной единственной причине: ты продолжаешь двигать обьект в момент коллизии вперед принудительно в сторону обьекта с которым ты прикасаешся на той же скорости** Если это сделать через флаг -- тряски не будет:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public float Speed = 1;
    private bool isGoingForward;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            isGoingForward = true;
        }

        if (isGoingForward)
            gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        isGoingForward = false;
    }
}
```

и результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему нужно писать именно так? Да потому, что мы работаем БЕЗ физического движка. Физический движок получает OnCollision и изменяет Скорость на нулевую или же изменяет скорость на меньшую но противоположную по вектору (Если Bouncines достаточно большая)

Если физика реализуется через движение нефизического рода, нужно учитывать то, что обьект может столкнутся с другим обьектом. И в таком случае дальше его двигать не имеет смысла или же нужно уменьшить скорость (как это делает физический движок).

Это логическая особенность работы с нефизическим движением, которую RiotBr3aker почему-то упустил. Формально - полчить удобоваримый результа без использования физики - реально. Другой момент - что писать костыли, все же, прийдется.

Comment: `тряски не будет` - будет, ровно до момента вызова `FixedUpdate`, работать с флагами, нежели отдать всю работу физике - это, вне сомнений, очень разумно.  Ты либо не до читал мой пост, либо решил пропустить эту **важную** деталь: каким образом физический движок обнаружит коллизию при огромной скорости в `Update`? CCD не будет работать в данном случае.

Comment: И нет `эта тряска на гифке возникает по одной единственной причине...` - это ты описал своими словами, круто, в моем ответе есть пояснение это проблемы на уровне терминов и проблем взаимодействия обоих потоков, какой смысл этого пояснения? Твое пояснение 1в1 повторяет мое, но без терминов.

Comment: Мое обьяснение рассказывает как обойти эфект тряски на практическом примере. Я не сказал что работать с флагами - это удобно. Где я такое говорил хотя бы раз? Более того, я всегда говорил что работа с физикой лучше чем без физики, прочитай мой ответ в вопросе про движение. Там на протяжении всей статьи показывалось что физическое движение лучше нефизического. ||| И прочитай мой ответ в вопросе с которого возник этот вопрос - я там прямым текстом писал что использование именно AddForce() настоятельно рекомендуется. Даже 2 (!!!) раза это написал за ответ прямым текстом!

Comment: А в чем смысл твоего ответа тогда? Чтобы был? Ну это плохой код с костыльным флагом, движение через `Update` далеко не всегда будет адекватно работать, мало того, что не всегда будут просчитываться столкновения, так это еще и самая простая сцена без сложного взаимодействия между хотя бы 2 динамическими объектами. Повторюсь, в чем смысл этого ответа в `каноническом вопросе` по Unity?

Comment: И я все еще жду ответа под моим вопросом про частоту `FixedUpdate` и `Update`, а то suvitruf что-то молчит, ну ты вроде бы согласился с ним.

Comment: В дополнении написанного тобой т.к. вместить это в коментарий под твоим ответом невозможно физически.

Comment: И кинь, пожалуста, линк. Я, наверное, что-то пропустил, а в ивентах SO найти не могу. Ты про что именно?

Comment: ну как костыльное решение - окей, пусть будет. Я про твой коммент под моим ответом: `"там только частота немного повыше". Наоборот, у FixedUpdate частота выше.`, ты с этим согласился, я ответил, почему я не согласен с этим, вот сижу, жду ответа :)

Comment: А и кстати, объект можно двигать только по флагу - окей, а что, если в этот самый объект прилетит сзади? Это будет считаться коллизией с установкой флага в ложь? Или нужно иметь вдобавок к этой системе еще и специальные метки/слои? Как разрешить такую ситуацию?