# Перемещение объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Unity есть много способов перемещать объект. В чем различие между этими подходами?

```
transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime); 

GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, v); 

GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(0, 0);
```

Правильно ли я понял, что 1 - это линейное перемещение, 2 - перемещение с постоянным ускорением, 3 - перемещение с плавным увеличением скорости и плавной остановкой?

Comment: Точно не помню в чем отличие,но операция GetComponent очень затратная и лучше ее не использовать когда нужно часто обращаться к объекту,а только когда 1 раз,например в функции Start()

Comment: transform.translate плохой способ, он нарушает состояние физ. движка..

Comment: 1) движение способом перерысовывания 2) Движения способом изменения вектора скорости 3) Движение способом применения силы к объекту (толкая)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, что такое "способ перерисовывания"?

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы лучше ориентироваться в вопросе, посмотрите следующие 2 вопроса:

1. [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)
2. [Движение с коллизией через Update и FixedUpdate, что такое “телепортация” в контексте физического движка в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-update-%D0%B8-fixedupdate-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82)

Теперь кратко по вашему вопросу:

1. `Translate()` - перемещение персонажа с помощью простого изменения его координаты, точнее сдвига позиции объекта, относительно его текущего положение. Это скорее не линейное перемещение, а "телепортация" объекта, так как объект резко меняет свое положение в пространстве. Это не физический способ перемещения, то есть прибегать к такому методу стоит только тогда, когда вы не используете физику для перемещения объекта, иначе могут случаться проблемы с коллизиями объектов (например несмотря на правильно настроенные `Rigidbody` и `Collider` один объект может застрять в другом. Кроме того, использовать такое перемещение стоит только в методе `Update()`, а не `FixedUpdate()`. Чем меньшее значение вы передадите в качестве параметра, тем менее "отрывистым" и плавным будет выглядеть ваше перемещение (но по факту, все-равно останется телепортацией)
2. `Rigidbody2D.velocity` - мгновенное изменение скорости физического объекта. Стоит применять с осторожностью, так как может приводить к физически нереалистичному поведению. В целом, при использовании физики в Unity скорость объекта будет вычисляться с учетом всех сил, которые действуют на физическое тело и массы физического объекта. По этому, если получится так, что физический движок посчитает за вас скорость объекта по всем силам, которые на него действуют, а затем вы измените ее руками, по средствам изменения `Rigidbody2D.velocity` - это может выглядеть неправильно. К этому методу стоит прибегать только в исключительных случаях, когда надо резко изменить движение объекта (сами Unity в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) приводят пример с прыжком персонажа). Стоит применять только в `FixedUpdate()`, и ни в коем случае не в `Update()`, а также избегать изменения позиции персонажа (`transform.Translate()` и изменение `transform.position`)
3. `Rigidbody2D.AddForce()` - добавить действие силы к объекту. Как уже писал в предыдущем пункте, физический движок вычисляет скорость и направление движения объекта опираясь на силы, которые действуют на объект, а также его массу. При этом способе "разгон" физического объекта будет более плавным. Если провести аналогию - применение этого способа - как будто вы толкнули физический объект в определенном направлении. Стоит применять только в `FixedUpdate()`, и ни в коем случае не в `Update()`, а также избегать изменения позиции персонажа (`transform.Translate()` и изменение `transform.position`)