# Объект перемещается при использовании setActive(false)

Tags: unity3d, pool

Проблема следующая. Есть некоторый объект стреляющий пулями. Пули при прохождении некоторого расстояния уничтожаются. Но для экономии ресурсов они деактивируются и помещаются в пулл, из которого затем при последующих выстрелах достаются и активируются. Проблема в том что перед тем как попасть на место выстрела они "мелькают"на месте их уничтожения(то есть они сначала перемещаются на место, где были разрушены и только потом отправляются на место выстрела), хотя позиция их смерти нигде не  запоминается. Более того оказывается что координата изменяется именно после метода setActive(false), что очень странно.
Вот код пулла:

```
public class PoolManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, LinkedList<GameObject>> poolsDictionary;
    private static Transform deactivatedObjectsParent;

    public static void init(Transform pooledObjectsContainer)
    {
        deactivatedObjectsParent = pooledObjectsContainer;
        poolsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, LinkedList<GameObject>>();

    }

    public static GameObject getGameObjectFromPool(GameObject prefab)
    {
        if (!poolsDictionary.ContainsKey(prefab.name))
        {
            poolsDictionary[prefab.name] = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
        }

        GameObject result;

        if (poolsDictionary[prefab.name].Count > 0)
        {
            result = poolsDictionary[prefab.name].First.Value;
            poolsDictionary[prefab.name].RemoveFirst();
            result.SetActive(true);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
            //Debug.Log(result.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position);
            result.name = prefab.name;

            return result;
        }

    }

    public static void putGameObjectToPool(GameObject target)
    {
        poolsDictionary[target.name].AddFirst(target);

        target.transform.parent = deactivatedObjectsParent;
        //здесь кордината еще (1000,1000)
        target.SetActive(false);
        //а здесь уже координата уничтожения


    }
}
```

Вот код пули:

```
    public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Rigidbody2D body;
    float startSpeed;
    float range;
    float coveredDistance;
    Vector2 lastPosition;
    void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }
    void Start()
    {
        coveredDistance = 0;
        lastPosition = body.position;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        coveredDistance += Mathf.Abs((body.position -  lastPosition).magnitude);//Рассчет пройденного расстояния
        lastPosition = body.position;
        if(coveredDistance>=range)//Уничтожение пули при прохождении расстояния стрельбы
        {
            //Destroy(gameObject);
            nullify();

            PoolManager.putGameObjectToPool(gameObject);

        }
    }
    public void create(float shipRotation,float startSpeed,float range,Vector2 shipVelocity)
    {
        //Debug.Log(shipRotation);
        this.startSpeed = startSpeed;
        this.range = range;
        body.rotation = shipRotation;
        body.velocity = new Vector2((float)-Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * body.rotation) * startSpeed+shipVelocity.x, (float)Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * body.rotation) * startSpeed+shipVelocity.y);
        lastPosition = body.position;
    }
    void nullify()//Функция обнуления
    {
        coveredDistance = 0;
        body.position = new Vector2(1000, 1000);

    }
}
```

И вот код самой стрельбы:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            GameObject bulletClone = PoolManager.getGameObjectFromPool(bullet);//получение ссылки на пулю из пула

            bulletClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector2(body.position.x - 1 * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * body.rotation), body.position.y + 1 * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * body.rotation));//выставление позиции пули

            bulletClone.GetComponent<BulletScript>().create(body.rotation,ammoSpeed,range,body.velocity);//Передача пуле ее характеристик 
        }
```

Из-за чего может быть такая проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы двигаете вашу "пулю" с помощью физики, а считаете пройденное расстояние (как и вызовы `nullify()` и возврат в пул) - реализуете в методе `Update()`, который никак не коррелирует с физикой. Более того, когда происходит `nullify()` вы явно изменяете координату объекта с помощью `body.position = new Vector2(1000, 1000);` при этом физика в общем-то продолжает работать, потому что приложенную при создании `velocity` объекта вы никак не обнуляете и не изменяете.

Смешивание физического и прямого перемещение объекта - очень плохая практика, которая выливается в подобного рода баги и коллизии, как у вас. Итого ваши ошибки по пунктам:

- Вы измеряете пройденное с помощью физики расстояние в `Update()`, что не верно, потому что физика обновляется не с частотой вызова `Update()`, а с частотой `FixedUpdate()`.
- Вы явно изменяете позицию объекта в `nullify()`, который вызывается в `Update()`, при этом физика у вас живет своей жизнью и продолжает обновляться и просчитываться в фоне.

Чтобы лучше разобраться в проблеме смешивания физического и реального перемещения объектов, почитайте следующие вопросы на ruSO, которые должны прояснить для вас всю ситуацию:

1. [Перемещение объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981527/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/981672#981672)
2. [Движение с коллизией через Update и FixedUpdate, что такое “телепортация” в контексте физического движка в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-update-%D0%B8-fixedupdate-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82)
3. [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)

Comment: Я изменил функцию update() на fixedUpdate() и ошибка действительно исчезла, но теперь ввод осуществляется в функции fixedUpdate() из-за чего он не всегда откликается, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ввод пользователя? если он будет в fixedUpdate - это дейcтвительно выразится в задержки ввода. Но в вашем коде я ввода не вижу, по этому и сказать ничего не могу. По идее как раз ввод вы можете оставить в Update и это будет правильней

Comment: Ввод можно увидеть в коде выстрела. Дело в том, что если он находится в Update(), то проблема остается

Comment: Как быстрое решение, можете, например в Update ставить какой-нибудь флаг, а сам флаг обрабатывать уже в FixedUpdate(). Либо сделать движение не физическим. Но это уже немного выходит за рамки начального вопроса.

Comment: Все разобрался, благодарю