# Как обработать соприкосновение 2D объектов?

Tags: unity3d

Игрок стреляет fireball'ами, которые не реагируют на соприкосновение с объектами. Пробовал две функции: OnTrigerEnter2D() и OnCollisionEnter2D(). Безрезультатно.

Код на fireball(префаб):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class fireball : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag != "Player")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Destroy(this);
        }
        Debug.Log("Test");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(10 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

На fireball'е весит тригер.
Также есть компоненты Circle Collider 2D и скрипт, приведенный выше. В Log ничего не выводит.

В чем проблема?

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter2D` вызывается? Собственно по этому коду он должен реагировать только на игрока

Comment: помимо коллайдера необходимо навесить RigidBody (в данном случае 2D)

Comment: Нельзя двигать физические объекты с помощью перемещения Transform'а. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-update-%d0%b8-fixedupdate-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82

Comment: @RiotBr3aker можно, но проверять придётся с помощью `if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(position, radius, layerMask) > 0) {}`. Для не слишком быстрых снарядов сгодится.

Comment: @Yaroslav можно, но это уже костыли ;)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker в данном случае конечно согласен ;)