# 2D Персонаж частично влазит в стену и дергается при сталкивании с этой стеной

Tags: unity3d

На персонаже есть Rigidbody2D, у стен с которыми он сталкивается этого нету. Я двигаю персонажа через transform.position. Когда персонаж сталкивается со стеной и идет в ее сторону, он за лазит в эту стену и его откидывает назад и получается дергание. Игра если что 2D. Смотрел на разных форумах, ничего для себя полезного не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. (Хотел загрузить видео сюда, но не разобрался как это сделать, надеюсь и без видео понятно про мою проблему))

Comment: Дайте угадаю: Вы не только двигаете через `transform`, но и делаете это в `Update()`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-update-%d0%b8-fixedupdate-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82

Comment: @RiotBr3aker мне нужно двигать персонажа через FixedUpdate и обязательно не через transform.position, а через rigidbody2d??

Comment: @RiotBr3aker дело в том, что когда я двигаю в FixedUpdate, у меня начинает подтормаживать анимация и иногда появляются баги, из-за которых персонаж не прыгает. Можно как-то по другому, но с Update?

Comment: Нет, по-другому нельзя. Разве что с какими-то хаками, а в эти дебри мне лезь не хочется + лень. Это уже конкретная реализация для конкретно вашего проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы двигаете RigidBody через transform.position , то RigidBody должен быть isKinematic == true.

Здесь либо двигать через isKinematic, но тогда персонаж не будет сталкиваться со стенами и надо будет самому решать, как быть с коллизиями и ограничивать персонажа, когда они возникают.

Или выключить isKinematic и двигать персонажа методами RigidBody в FixedUpdate(). Сейчас у вас происходят рассинхронизированные события: физика отталкивает персонажа, а вы в свою очередь, в Update() пихаете его обратно. Расчет физики и Update() не совпадают друг с другом.