# Получить объект по точке. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу 2d игру на Unity и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: персонаж дрожит возле коллайдера(что не удивительно, так как зайти в коллайдер он не может). Я придумал следующее: проверять через код координаты следующей точки игрока перед перемещением его туда, и, если там есть коллайдер, просто не перемещать. Вопрос в том как это реализовать. Если есть лучшие варианты решить эту проблему, буду рад выслушать, но, все же, мне интересен ответ и на мой вопрос.

Comment: Придумка конечно "классная". А задаваться вопросом, почему у тебя дрожит, а у других нет не пробывал? `Google: unity3d как двигать персонажа`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Движение с коллизией через Update и FixedUpdate, что такое "телепортация" в контексте физического движка в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-update-%d0%b8-fixedupdate-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: у вас неправильно реализовано передвижение объекта. Такие вопросы уже были, посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-update-%d0%b8-fixedupdate-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82)  вопрос

Comment: и до кучи, почитайте еще [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0) вопрос, чтобы до конца разобраться в теме