# Перемещение по вертикальной и горизонтальной оси в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пробую свои силы в c# Unity. Пытаюсь задать передвижение как по вертикальной, так и по горизонтальной оси.

```
void Update()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.up * moveY * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Однако, части кода конфликтуют. При таком подключении перемещение по горизонтали попросту не работает. Подскажите, в чем проблема???

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: Почитайте [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/251749) и  [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/960529/251749). Скорее всего этой информации вам хватит для реализации правильного перемещения

Comment: К сожалению, вы не поняли моего вопроса. Я спрашивал, как разобраться с конфликтующими частями управления. Разобрался уже сам.

Comment: к сожалению, у вас и передвижение сделано неправильно, отсюда и конфликты ваши