# UNITY Почему персонаж двигается рывками телепортируясь?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
  public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

}

Вот код, использовал новую систему ввода, персонаж падает с гравитацией 0.001 при выставленной 1 и двигается рывками какими-то рандомными сам по себе + телепортируется вверх (пробел не жму). Если через transform.Translate, то всё нормально, но физическое движение красивее. Что делать?

Comment: попробуй в fixedupdate использовать rb.velocity вместо moveposition и не умножай на deltatime

Comment: Как тело может падать или прыгать, если вы не даёте этого сделать, задавая новый вектор движения каждый фрейм.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Движение с коллизией через Update и FixedUpdate, что такое "телепортация" в контексте физического движка в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960529/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-update-%d0%b8-fixedupdate-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: @Psyxoz0x13 убрал движение из Update и закинул rb.velocity в FixedUpdate, персонаж передвигается отлично, но дальше падает ооочень медленно и не прыгает

Comment: @Yaroslav И как это решить?